# Passing state from one component to another with React language switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, react-props

I am translating my React App with headless CMS. I have a language switcher in my navbar and on each component has to be the specified language.

The language Switcher logic:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState('en-us');

const handleEnglish = () => {
    cookies.set('chosenLang', 'en-us');
    setSelected('en-us');
};

<button onClick={handleEnglish}>EN</button>

const handleFrench = () => {
    cookies.set('chosenLang', 'fr-fr');
    setSelected('fr-fr');
};

<button onClick={handleFrench}>FR</button>
```

And logic in component based on which the language is recognised (pretty simple):

```
{lang: selected}
```

This works, but just because the language switcher is in the same file as translated component. Once I created separate component for navbar (where is the lang switch) it does not work and I don't know how to pass the state of it to other components)

I tried in my page component to do something like `<Navbar {...selected} />`, how I would normally pass the props but no luck with that.

Comment: Can you please show us more code snippets please?

Comment: Sure I can @PriyankKachhela, but I don't really know what ? This is basically all what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/languagecontext-example-t33pm

You can you context or redux, react-redux to share state between components across app.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the context API, the selected language state is available only locally in that component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context